# Automate a R function t

Tags: r

I am trying to put a query in R for all my columns I want to create a new columns that will say impact or non impacted depending of my previous columns info. 
All Range$X01...to Range$X12 represent my columns tested

my code is a If condition

```
if (Range$X01=="0" | Range$X02=="0"| Range$X03=="0"| Range$X04=="0" | Range$X05=="0" | Range$X06=="0" | Range$X07=="0" | Range$X08=="0" |Range$X09=="0"| Range$X10=="0"| Range$X11=="0" |Range$X12=="0") {
  Range$Status="Impacted"
} else {
      Range$Status="Non Impacted"
}
```

My variables are categorical.

It doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Use ``` characters before and after your code, so it will be look like a code.

Comment: Are your variables really strings? Do you really want `Range$X01=="0"` instead of `Range$X01==0` ?

Comment: `with(Range, ifelse(X01=='0' | X02=='0' | ... | X12 == '0', "Impacted", "Not Impacted"))`

Comment: Dynamically: `ifelse(rowSums((Range[,grep("^X[0-9]+", colnames(Range), value=TRUE)] == '0') > 0), "Imp", "Not")`

Comment: my variable values are categorical D0 to D4

Comment: y$ll<- apply(y,1, function(v) ifelse(sum(v=="d2")==2 || unlist(v) %in% c("d3","d4"),1,0))  gave me the correct result but not for 2 d2 in a row considering 0 results in between

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not vectorized so it wont check the values line by line but just the first and assigns a constant to `Status` depending on whether there is a zero in your first row. You can use `if_else` instead, which is actually vectorized (checks a vector element by element.

By using `dplyr`, its `select_helpers` and some tweaks, you can get what you want in a few lines of code

```
library(dplyr)
Range %>% 
  mutate(Status = if_else(Range %>% 
                       # select all variables that start with X followed by 01 to 12
                       select(num_range(prefix = "X", range = 1:12, width = 2)) %>%
                       # check each selected cell whether it is equal to 0 
                       `==`(., 0) %>% 
                       # count the rowsums. since TRUE is considered as 1 and FALSE as
                       # 0, a rowsum greather than 0 indicates that at least one variable 
                       # must have been zero in that row
                       rowSums(na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
                       # converting it back to a logical where 0 is considered as FALSE 
                       # and positive values as TRUE, so multiple zeros boil down to TRUE
                       as.logical(), 
                     # if TRUE
                     "Impacted", 
                     # if FALSE
                     "Not Impacted"))
```

Comment: if I want to modify it for 2 d2 in a row = impacted or any d3 or d4 = impacted else not impacted